# Wall frame weirdness during renovations

Tags: drywall, concrete, walls, framing

so I am renovating my garage and noticed something in 2 spots along the frame when ripping down the drywall.

Here is a photo:

[image: framing anchor weirdness]

The walls of the garage have stood for many many years without major issue, but I am just not sure what I should do here. It looks like when they dropped the anchor bolts for the wall frames, they put a couple to far out so they just slapped a piece of 2x4 on the others side of the bolt.

I am not even sure it is actually supporting the wall.

I am mainly curious if I should be concerned and what to do when I go about putting up the new drywall, having this piece of wood stick out is an eyesore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunch is correct - the anchor bolt in the picture obviously isn't doing a whole lot. If the scabbed on 2x4 bothers you, just remove it, cut the existing anchor bolt off flush with the concrete, and put in a new anchor through the center of the base plate.

Comment: I have only put anchor bolts in fresh concrete, never added one; do you just use some sort of epoxy compound to do it? Would be OK to just leave it as is, your opinion?

Comment: I'd re-anchor it. There are numerous ways to do this - I've usually used drive pin anchors for stuff like this. https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=drive+pin+anchors&tbm=shop

Comment: Simpson Strong-Tie makes anchor bolts for use in earthquake retrofit. Run a hammer drill down through the concrete, squeeze the epoxy out of the caulk gun through the mixer spout and ram the bolt home before the epoxy sets. Drop the washer on and tighten the nut down to firmly anchor the bottom plate to the foundation.